# Get Google Analytics ID with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract the Google analytics ID from a html document.

I found the following function:

```
function get_UA() {

txt = document.getElementById('scripttag').value;

var matches = txt.match(/(UA-[\d-]+)/);

if (matches[1]) {

    alert(matches[1]);

}

}
```

But im getting this error:

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating
>   'document.getElementById('scripttag').value')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Can you access the _gaq variable? If you can, and the page is using asynchronous tracking...

```
var accountId = _gaq._getAsyncTracker()._getAccount();
```

Comment: For the new [Universal Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en) where `_gaq` has been translated to `ga` you could use: `ga.getAll().shift().b.data.w[':trackingId']`

Answer (score 2):

In April 2017, this works:

`ga.getAll()[0].b.data.values[':trackingId']`

Answer (score 2):

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('trackingId')
```

if you already have a tracker you can obtain it with

```
tracker.get('trackingId')
```

**Carefull**, Dont forget [google analytics best practices](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ga-object-methods-reference)

> Don't use ga object methods outside a readyCallback as the methods may not be available yet.